# Link Excel Cell to redirect to a sheet of same name

Tags: excel, vba

Good day,

I a new to VBA/Macro's and I am working in Excel. What I need to do is take a value in a specific cell (A4) and use that obtained value to go to a sheet in the same workbook with the same name. Thus in my dropdown in cell A4 I have 8 different options and dependent on this I need to go to a sheet with the same name.

Please help.

Comment: Hello MM13, 
Welcome to Stackoverflow! What have you tried? Post your code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is a Data Validation `DropDown` placed in the Excel Worksheet cell "A4", refer to the following VBA code snippet to achieve the result (i.e. switch to the Worksheet on `DropDown` select event):

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$4" Then
        Worksheets(Range("$A$4").Value).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thx Alex, I probably should be more clear. I have a cell in a sheet "MAN" that is populated by a Sumifs function (=SUMIFS(Sheet4!Movement,Sheet4!Master,$A$1,Sheet4!ulGLExpenseCategory,$A$4,Sheet4!Period,"="&D2) where it gets information from a "Sheet4" based on values in the "MAN" sheet. What I want to do is to be able to display the data in "Sheet4" that makes up this field in the "MAN" sheet. Pretty much the same as a Drill Down in a Pivot table.

Comment: You are welcome. It's hard to read the code placed in comments, and it's not a generally recommended practice. Please mark the answer accepted if it satisfies the original question, and should you have more questions, please post them separately. Best regards,